# How can I concat 2 columns with eachother without using Raw Sql Concat

Tags: sql, laravel, concatenation

I am working on a new project in Laravel 8 where I am allowed to use as little RAW SQL as possible.
For a number of situations I have to Concat 2 columns together (as it is shown below) and that is actually easy to do with Raw Sql. But I am not allowed to use Raw Sql for that.

```
BoekhoudingVerdichting::select('boekhouding_verdichting.id', DB::raw("CONCAT(boekhouding_verdichting.verdichtingnr,' - ',verdichting) AS verdichting, CONCAT(boekhouding_hoofdverdichting.hoofdverdichtingnr,' - ',hoofdverdichting) AS hoofdverdichting"))
            ->join('boekhouding_hoofdverdichting', function ($q) {
                $q->on('boekhouding_hoofdverdichting.id', 'boekhouding_verdichting.id_hoofdverdichting');
            })
            ->join('boekhouding_grootboek', function ($q) {
                $q->on('boekhouding_grootboek.id_verdichting', 'boekhouding_verdichting.id');
            })
            ->groupBy('boekhouding_verdichting.id')
            ->orderBy('boekhouding_verdichting.verdichtingnr')
            ->orderBy('boekhouding_verdichting.verdichting')
            ->get();
```

[image]

- I got a tip that I first have to get the data from the database as a Collection (as it is shown below) and then put the Collection through a map-function and in the map-function I can Concat the columns and return them! I searched the internet but I couldn't find any soloution.
- Maybe you have another solution?

I hope you can help me with it.

```
BoekhoudingVerdichting::select('boekhouding_verdichting.id', 'boekhouding_verdichting.verdichtingnr', 'verdichting', 'boekhouding_hoofdverdichting.hoofdverdichtingnr', 'hoofdverdichting')
            ->join('boekhouding_hoofdverdichting', function ($q) {
                $q->on('boekhouding_hoofdverdichting.id', 'boekhouding_verdichting.id_hoofdverdichting');
            })
            ->join('boekhouding_grootboek', function ($q) {
                $q->on('boekhouding_grootboek.id_verdichting', 'boekhouding_verdichting.id');
            })
            ->groupBy('boekhouding_verdichting.id')
            ->orderBy('boekhouding_verdichting.verdichtingnr')
            ->orderBy('boekhouding_verdichting.verdichting')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem!

```
$collection = BoekhoudingVerdichting::select('boekhouding_verdichting.id', 'boekhouding_verdichting.verdichtingnr', 'verdichting', 'boekhouding_hoofdverdichting.hoofdverdichtingnr', 'hoofdverdichting')
            ->join('boekhouding_hoofdverdichting', function ($q) {
                $q->on('boekhouding_hoofdverdichting.id', 'boekhouding_verdichting.id_hoofdverdichting');
            })
            ->join('boekhouding_grootboek', function ($q) {
                $q->on('boekhouding_grootboek.id_verdichting', 'boekhouding_verdichting.id');
            })
            ->groupBy('boekhouding_verdichting.id')
            ->orderBy('boekhouding_verdichting.verdichtingnr')
            ->orderBy('boekhouding_verdichting.verdichting')
            ->get();


$newCollection = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) {
            
            $item['verdichting'] = $item['verdichtingnr'] . ' - ' . $item['verdichting'];

$item['hoofdverdichting'] = $item['hoofdverdichtingnr'] . ' - ' . $item['hoofdverdichting'];

            return $item;
        });


$solved = $newCollection->all();
```